# How to prove $b^n-1 \geq n(b-1)$ for $b>1$ and $n \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have already figured out a simple proof by induction for this problem. Is there any other way to do it?

> Prove $b^n-1 \geq n(b-1)$. For $b>1$ and $n \geq 0$.

Comment: Well what is your proof?

Comment: I don't think you can use induction because $n$ is not discrete.

Comment: @user2770287: $n$ is not a natural number?

Comment: It's true for $b>0$. That's  a version of *Bernoulli's inequality*

Comment: @user2770287 Just looked at Baby Rudin, it seems that $n$ is indeed a natural number for this particular problem. So he can definitely use induction on $n$.

Comment: Your title is confusing: is Walter Rudin an interesting inequality?

Comment: take $b=4, n =0.5$ then the conclusion is not true

Comment: Could someone check if the hypothesis on $b$ isn't $b>0$ rather than $b>1$?

Comment: I have edited title (see the comment of @Mariano). Still if you want to add that source of the problem is one of Rudin's book, I think it would be a useful addition to the question. But you should give a precise citation. (Name of the book, edition, page, number of the exercise, ...)

Comment: @Bernard OP never indicated that $n$ are non negative numbers. This problem isn't even correct for real number $n$.

Comment: @user2770287: I  beg you r pardon? What's $n\ge 0$  in the title then?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, I meant he never said $n$ is an integer.

Comment: That's another problem. I doubt  Rudin denoted $n$ a non-integer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the inequality is true for all $\color{red}{b>0}$.

The initialisation is trivial.

*Inductive step:*

Suppose $b^n-1>n(b-1)$  for some $n>1$. Rewrite this as $b^n>1+n(b-1)$ and multiply both sides by $b=b-1+1$, which is positive. We get:
\begin{align*}b^{n+1}&>1+b-1+n(b-1+1)(b-1)=1+(n+1)(b-1)+n(b-1)^2\\&>1+(n+1)(b-1).\end{align*}

Comment: The first equality on the last line is false...

Comment: You're right. However, I'm sure of the result: $b>0$ is enough.

Comment: Yes, it is true tha for *all* $b$, $b(b-1)\geq b-1$

Comment: OK, I've found the typo. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. Still wrong. Now the last equality is wrong. You need to get rid of the $b^2$, which requires an additional inequality

Comment: Fixed. It's getting late here…

Answer (score 16):

$$b^n-1=(b-1)(b^{n-1}+\cdots+b+1)\ge(b-1)(1+\cdots+1)=n(b-1).$$

Comment: you arenot right use Geometric Series for $\frac{1}{b}$

Comment: For natural $n$, lovely proof.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is an exercise from Principles of Mathematical Analysis. $n\in\Bbb N_+$ is a hypothesis. :) The exercise is from Chapter 1 before derivatives and integrals are defined.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x) = x^n$, then [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says that there exists $c \in (1,b)$ such that $f(b) - f(1) = f'(c)(b-1)$, i.e. $$b^n - 1 = nc^{n-1}(b-1)$$
thus $b^n - 1 > n(b-1)$ since $c >1$. Actually we can see that one needs $n \geq 1$(or $n=0$) for the conclusion to be true

Answer (score 2):

**MVT**: Consider $f(x) = x^n \Rightarrow f'(x) = nx^{n-1} \geq n, x \geq 1 \Rightarrow f(b) - f(1) = f'(c)(b-1) \Rightarrow b^n-1 \geq n(b-1)$

**Bernoulli**: Take $b = 1+a, a > 0 \Rightarrow b^n - 1 = (1+a)^n - 1 \geq 1+an-1 = an = n(b-1)$.

Comment: Awesome Solution

Comment: Note, Bernoulli needs $n \ge 1$...

Answer (score 1):

One way: $b^n-1=(b-1)(1+b+...+b^{n-1})>(b-1)()1+1+...+1) =n(b-1)$

Other way: consider function $f(b)=b^n-1-n(b-1)$, for $b>1$. Taking derivative and conculde that it's increasing on $b \in (1,\infty)$. Thus $f(b)>f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is another answer: we have that 
$$(b - 1) ( b^{n - 1} + b^{n - 2} + \cdots + b + 1) = b^{n} - 1.$$
This means that we can write 
$$ \frac{b^n - 1}{b - 1} = b^{n - 1} + b^{n - 2} + \cdots + b + 1.$$
The right hand side has $n$ terms all of which (by hypothesis on $b$) are greater than or equal to 1; thus we can conclude that 
$$ \frac{b^n - 1}{b - 1} \ge n.$$

Comment: Your answer is the same as Tim Raczkowski's.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another way...

**Case 1:**  $b, n \ge 1$

$$x > 1\implies x^{n-1} \ge 1 \implies \int_1^b x^{n-1} dx \ge \int_1^b 1 dx \implies b^n-1 \ge n(b-1)$$

**Case 2:**  $b \in (0, 1)$ and $n \ge 1$.

$$x < 1\implies x^{n-1} \le 1 \implies \int_b^1 x^{n-1} dx \le \int_b^1 1 dx \implies b^n-1 \ge n(b-1)$$

Note however that if $n \in (0, 1)$ your inequality **does not hold**, rather the reverse does.  Same proof...

Answer (score 0):

I had also noticed @PetiteEtincelle's counterexample, $(b,n) = (4,\frac{1}{2})$.  And this suggested an intended fixup and proof...

The stated inequality holds for $b,n \in [1,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

True by inspection at $b=1,n=1$.  In fact, true by inspection at $b=1, n \in [1,\infty)$.  Partial differentiation with respect to $b$ gives $n b^{n-1} \geq n$ which is evidently strictly true for $b>1, n>1$.  So for any point $(b,n) \in [1,\infty) \times [1,\infty)$, we can start at $(1,n)$, where the stated inequality holds, then increase the first coordinate to $b$, and the inequality will hold at every point along the path (because our derivative shows the "big side" grows strictly faster along this path than the "small side").

BTW:  Before anyone "complains"...  Yes, I know that the notation "$n$" suggests that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$.  But "$b$" doesn't suggest anything, so using "obvious" default domains isn't so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Proof By Induction: 

Inductive Hypothesis: $b^{n}-1\geq n(b-1)$

Base: $n=0$. $0=0$ True.

 Inductive Step:

$b^{n+1}-1\geq (n+1)(b-1)$

$b^{n+1}-1\geq n(b-1)+b-1$

$b^{n+1}\geq n(b-1)+b$

$b*b^{n}\geq b*[n(b-1)+1]$
$b*[n(b-1)+1]\geq n(b-1)+b$ $\implies b\geq 1$, Hypothesis. QED